# How to concat a SESSION variable and GET variable?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to concat `$_SESSION["username"]` with `$q`. I've tried several ways but can't seem to concat the two.

**Attempts**

```
VALUES ('".$_SESSION["username"] + $q."', '".$_SESSION["username"]."', '$q')
VALUES ('".$_SESSION["username"]." + $q', '".$_SESSION["username"]."', '$q')
VALUES ('".$_SESSION["username"]. + $q"', '".$_SESSION["username"]."', '$q')
```

I've looked up string operators but I think the syntax is slightly different with the `$_SESSION[]` variable.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dot operator to concatenate strings in PHP:

```
VALUES ('" .$_SESSION["username"] . $q . "', '" .$_SESSION["username"]. "', '$q')
```

Note that your code is subject to SQL injection.

Comment: It wasn't working but I realized there has to be a period on the right side of $q too. Thanks!